# counting a data type non-recursively

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj

I have a datatype:

```
datatype int A = leaf of int * string
               | trunk of int * (int A) list
```

Say if I have test: int A, then I would like to count the leafs and trunks in test and return them as a couple: (#leafs,#trunks). However I do not want to use recursion.

This was my attempt:

```
  fun count(test: int A): int*int =
      case test
         of trunk(a,l) =>
            let
               val l1 = List.filter(fn trunk(a',l') => true
                                     | _ => false) l
               val l2 = List.filter(fn leaf(a',s) => true
                                     | _ => false) l
            in
               (List.length(l2), List.length(l1) + 1)
            end
          | leaf(a,s) => (1, 0)
```

This works as long as l' is nil. As you can see, I separate the tress and trunks into different lists and return the length.
However, l' can contain other leafs and trunks that are not getting counted. Notice this is not recursive. I've been thinking of trying to use continuation but I dont know how to do so.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you help me know why you don't want to use recursion here? It is a very natural way to reason here.

Comment: I would rather like to use list operations like reduce and map! This is a way to do things differently.

Comment: Lets consider a simpler datatype (`datatype 'a tree = trunk of 'a tree list`) and an example. How would you find the number of trunks for this trunk thingy `val x = trunk( [trunk( [trunk( [] )] )] )`

Comment: Given the recursive nature of your data structure, it will be difficult for you to avoid recursion. You can avoid *explicit* recursion by writing map and reduce functions for your tree.

Comment: @molbdnilo you're indeed correct. I wrote an explicit reduce function that helped me count. thank you

Comment: Sarah, can you share your answer? This way somebody else can learn from your solution and you can answer your own question. Checkout http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since our datatype is different from lists, we need to make an explicit reduce function for it. This reduce function takes in a function (ff) that is applied to every leaf. It also takes in a function (fd) that is applied to every trunk and recursively combining the result. It looks like this:

```
  fun reduce(ff:('a*string -> 'b))(fd:('a * 'b list -> 'b))(s: int A): 'b =
      case s
         of leaf(a, d) => ff(a,d)
          | trunk(a, l)  => fd(a, List.map(fn x => reduce(ff)(fd)(x)) l)
```

Finally our count function will look like this:

> fun count(s: int A): int*int =
>
> ```
>   let
>      val i = reduce(fn x => 1)(fn (y,l) => foldr op+ 0 l)(s)
>      val i' = reduce(fn x => 0)(fn (y,l) => 1 + foldr op+ 0 l)(s)
>   in
>      (i, i')
>   end
> ```

That is, in (i) if a leaf is found replace it with 1 and if a trunk is found replace it with 0 and sum the whole list. 
In (i'), if a leaf was found replace it with 0. Otherwise add 1 if a trunk is found and sum!